# Playframework 2 using Jquery to request from server

Tags: jquery, playframework

I want to do a request with JQuery to a application method wich has a String arg, but I have a problem passing the value of the string.
In my HTML I have this script:

```
<script>
var search;
$("#search").keyup(function () {
    if($(this).val() != search){
        search = $(this).val();
        //alert(search);
        $.get("@routes.Application.autocomplete("+search+")", function (data) {
            //some stuff will be done here   
        });
        return false;
    }
}).keyup();
```

My Application method is like:

```
public static Result autocomplete(String search) {
    System.out.println("Searching for: "+search);
    final List<String> response = new ArrayList<String>();
    response.add("test1");
    response.add("test2");
    return ok(Json.toJson(response));

}
```

What happens is that JQuery is not sending the value of **search** var but instead sending a string **"search"**.

How can I do the concatenation of the string inside JQuery Get()?

Thanks

Comment: you using reserve routing for ajax request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo **can not** mix server-side variables (ie. `@routes.C.a(somevar)`) with typical client-side elements, that's obvious!  Isn't it?

1. Use some inspector tool to check the rendered HTML, you will understand
2. Check in jQuery docs, how to pass params with ajax requests
3. Get little bit more familiar with routing and using JS in framework's views

Tips:

1. Make a `search` param in the route as an optional one

   ```
   GET /autocomplete  controllers.Application.autocomplete(search: String ?= "")
   ```
2. Use 'almost normal' way of building AJAX queries:

   ```
   // cut...
   $.get("@routes.Application.autocomplete()",
        { search: search },
        function (data) {
           //some stuff ...
        }
   );
   // cut...
   ```
3. validate the incoming value if it isn't `empty` or `null` and return `badRequest()` (probably in JSON format) in such case.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use the reverse routing and make your ajax call in this way:

Javascript code:

```
var ajaxProps = jsRoutes.controllers.Application.subscribe(self.emailSuscriber());
$.ajax({
 type: ajaxProps.method,
 url: ajaxProps.url,
}).done(function( msg ) {
   self.alertMessage(msg);
});
```

Java server code:
controller.Aplication

```
public static Result subscribe(String email){
/* suscribe code */
}

public static Result javascriptRoutes() {
    response().setContentType("text/javascript");
    return ok(
        Routes.javascriptRouter("jsRoutes",
                controllers.routes.javascript.Application.suscribe()));
 }
```

Routes file

```
  GET  /subscribe/:email               controllers.Application.subscribe(email:String)

  GET  /public/javascripts/routes      controllers.Application.javascriptRoutes()
```

In your HTML template include:

```
   <script src="@routes.Application.javascriptRoutes"> type="text/javascript"</script>
```